# Sentence struture - Reversing and starting with No

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, passive-voice, sentence-usage

"No Software will be developed for this project".

1. What's wrong with above sentence?
2. I get a "Passive voice (consider reversing)" suggestion on the "will be" part from Word grammar checker. However, I don't see a need to reverse it when not sure who/when that particular action take place. Apart from that, Is it grammatically correct or not?
3. Can it be rephrased in better way because i feel it is bit harsh when read.
4. Is it generally ok to structure a sentence starting with no?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your sentence, *software* is capitalized when it shouldn't be (unless it is a proper noun, which I assume it is not).
2. Apparently (according to [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Microsoft-Word-tell-me-to-consider-revising-every-time-I-use-passive-voice)), Microsoft Word  gives *passive voice: consider revising* because the active voice is used more than the passive voice, so it gives feedback to suggest using active voice instead.
3. I will assume that the sentence is written as

> No **s**oftware will be developed for this project.

It doesn't sound harsh, but you could rephrase it to move the negative away from the beginning:

> Software **won't** *(will not)* be developed for this project.

4. Yes, it is perfectly okay to start a sentence with no, but in spoken English it is much more common to find negative contractions instead:

> **No** person should use the elevator in a fire.
>
> People **shouldn't** *(should not)* use the elevator in a fire.
>
> ---
>
> **No** human has three legs.
>
> Humans **don't** *(do not)* have three legs.